# C++ strtod is not reading an argument type correctly

Tags: c++

I'm working through Programming - Principles and Practise by Bjarne Stroustrup and a fairly simple drill has me stumped (this is only part 2 of 11).

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

//Write a program that consists of a while loop (each time around the loop) reads in two ints and then prints them. Exit the program when a terminating | is entered.

int main()
{
    char temp;
    char* endptr = 0;
    while (temp != '|')
    {
        double value;
        vector<int> values;
        for (string temp; values.size() < 2;)
        {
            cin >> temp;
            {
                if (temp == "|")
                    break;
                else
                    value = strtod(temp, &endptr); 
                    values.push_back(value);
            }
        }
        cout << values[0] << "\n" << values[1] << "\n" << "\n";
        values.clear();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2017 is giving me an error here:

```
else
    value = strtod(temp, &endptr);
```

with the argument `temp` advising "no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists", which is exactly the function I expected strtod to be.

Comment: `strtod()` is a C library function that knows absolutely nothing about this bizarre C++ class called `std::string` that you are attempting to pass to it as a parameter. And I somehow doubt it, very much, that any book written by Stroustrup will tell you to pass a `std::string` to `strtod`(). That is un-possible.

Comment: Call `c_str` on the string to get a `char*`.

Comment: Also, you seem to have a `using namespace std;` in your `std_lib_facilities.h` header file, don't do that, ever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are correct that I have not been told to use strtod(), that was the suggestion of a friend-programmer offering advice. Your answer has helped me understand why strtod() will not work as implemented, what alternatives are there for me to check my input for | to terminate?

Comment: @Pezo the header file is provided by the author to use until chapter 8-12 (I am on 4) and have not yet covered namespaces. Thanks for the advice but at present it means nothing to me although I'll endeavour to refer to this when I approach namespaces and header files.

Comment: Stroustrup is telling you to put `using namespace std;` into a header file, even if temporary?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I got it from the link in the text:

_"For your first programs we strongly suggest that you use the custom header file std\_lib\_facilities.h from www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std\_lib\_facilities.h_ "...[Place a copy of it in the directory...]" with no further comments on the header file or why it is recommended, just basic usage instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are in C++, use `std::stod()` instead (C++11)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Comment: Thanks Matt, however, I'm having a similar error with stod() as [here](https://i.imgur.com/2mv7rts), could you possibly advise?

Comment: @Pezo I understood I am probably doing something wrong however "just learn how to x" isn't a particularly constructive comment. I have looked at the link provided by Matthieu however if I was able to find my own solution by staring at the page I would have done so by now. 

The act of extracting a solution from existing sources is exactly what I would like to learn through advice from those already experienced at the same, through StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across the wrong way, didn't see Matthieu had already posted that same link. Maybe it's my experience speaking, but to me the page has all the information you need. Pass in a pointer to a `std::size_t` that will receive the index past the end of the converted number.

Comment: @Pezo Not at all no need to apologise, I'm thankful you're willing to help! It's almost certainly a case of it looking more complex than it is, but I don't currently have the experience of filtering out the complexities.

Having looked again at the code I like to Matthieu is that not what I am doing? Line 7 I initialize the pointer and it's the second argument passed to stod(). 

I'm going to go back and reread the last chapter as I don't feel confident with pointers at all, so don't feel pressure to reply if you're busy!